How to simulate this AR(1): Xt =2+0.8(Xt_1 −2)+εt series in R?
I want to simulate an AR(1) model defined as follows:
$$X_t = 2 + 0.8(X_{t-1} −2) + \varepsilon t$$
but I do not know how to interpret the constant $2$ in this term.
How do I simulate this in R?

The $2$s are presumably supposed to represent the "central" value of the time series: if it deviates too far from $2$, it will more often than not move back towards $2$.

The most pedestrian approach actually works well in R, as exemplified by this two-line solution (which sets $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon)=(1/2)^2$).  It is exactly parallel to the mathematical formula, term by term. mu <- 2; x <- eps <- rnorm(200, 0, 1/2); for (t in tail(seq_along(eps), -1)) x[t] <- mu + 0.8 * (x[t-1] - mu) + eps[t]
